# Splitting the key and reducing further in Hadoop map reduce

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on a mapReduce assignment in Scala. I have a key value pair. I would like to remove the part of the key as the main key with other part of key as a json value .

```
2:40 INFO   4
2:40 WARN   3
3:10 INFO   7
3:10 WARN   3
```

The keys are '2:40 INFO','2:40 WARN' and the value is the int value following the key. I would like for my reducer to make it into

```
2:40 {INFO : 4, WARN : 3}
3:10 {INFO : 7, WARN : 3}
```

The code used for the reducer is

```
  class Reduce extends MapReduceBase with Reducer[Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable] :
    override def reduce(key: Text, values: util.Iterator[IntWritable], output: OutputCollector[Text, IntWritable], reporter: Reporter): Unit =
      val line = key.toString
      line.split(" ").foreach(token=>
      println("")
      )
      val sum = values.asScala.reduce((valueOne, valueTwo) => new IntWritable(valueOne.get() + valueTwo.get()))
      output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum.get()))
```

Answer (score 0):

> The keys are '2:40 INFO','2:40 WARN'

You'll have 4 separate reducer functions get ran (one for each unique key), and therefore there's nothing you can do to "reduce further" by.

In your mapper code, you'd need to output only the time as the key, and the rest of the line in whatever format you want (such as JSON), as **Text**, then your reducer would **already get** the below inputs (assuming you did nothing with the remainder of the line)

```
2:40 ["INFO   4", "WARN   3"] 
3:10 ["INFO   7", "WARN   3"]
```

So, basically, you don't need to process the reducer parameters at all unless some time **+LEVEL** can exist more than once in your file.

In this case, you'd need something like this (my Scala is bad, so this is Java)

```
Map<String, Long> counts = new HashMap<>();
for (Text v : values) {
    String[] parts = v.toString().split("\\s+");  // assuming nothing was done the the input 
    String level = parts[0];
    long count = Long.parseLong(parts[1]);

    counts.put(level, count + counts.getOrDefault(level, 0));
} 
// or change hashmap into different output format 
output.collect(key, new Text(counts.toString()));
```

Again, reducer output also needs to be **Text** and your imports should be `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce._`, not deprecated `mapred._`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try implementing this.